# Minecraft: Java Edition stuck on download

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

So, I currently have Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition installed on my computer, and I wanted to play the Java Edition as well.

But once I was finally able to actually get the java launcher to work, the download gets stuck at **158.39/309.57** and then an error occurs. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?[image]

```
Failed to download file.
Name: is_is.json
URL: https://resources.download.minecraft.net/3f/3fa5d6ee471a4b9a49cd347193dd780cd93d8331
Error details: Operation too slow. Less than 30 bytes/sec transferred the last 60 seconds
Filename on disk: 3fa5d6ee471a4b9a49cd347193dd780cd93d8331
Path: C:\Users\joesp\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\3f\3fa5d6ee471a4b9a49cd347193dd780cd93d8331
Exists: File
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering this problem, the solution I have found (on 2 separate computers) is to simply restart the computer.